# Delta: Flight from PHL to LAS with connecting at ATL

Tags: luggage, delta-air-lines

We are traveling from Philadelphia to Las Vegas on Delta. There is a layover at ATL for 1 hour 20 minutes. We will have 1 check-in luggage. The query is that can we put the luggage as through so that we finally collect it at Las vegas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you have booked the journey as a single ticket, you can check your bag in Philadelphia and it will be automatically transferred in Atlanta so that you can collect it in Las Vegas.  This is standard for US domestic flights.